# ExpandableListView child order is incorrect after filter

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-filterable

Hey guys this is how I added stuff to my expandablelist..

```
listDataHeader = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Afghanistan",
            "Albania",
            "Algeria",
            "Andorra",
            "Angola",
            "Anguilla",
            "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Argentina",
            "Armenia",
            "Aruba",`........`
```

listDataChild = new HashMap>();

```
// Adding child data
List<String> Afghanistan = new ArrayList<String>();
Afghanistan.add("Dari");
Afghanistan.add("Pashto");


List<String> Albania = new ArrayList<String>();
Albania.add("Albanian");
Albania.add("Greek");

List<String> Algeria = new ArrayList<String>();
Algeria.add("Arabic");
Algeria.add("French");
Algeria.add("Berber Dialects");
```

after the filtering

```
private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = originalData;
            final HashMap<String, List<String>> childList = originalDatachild;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);
            final HashMap<String, List<String>> nlistChild= new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            int counterFilter=0;
            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                    /*int ii = i;
                    counterFilter++;
                    while(childList.get(ii)!=null) {
                        nlistChild.put(nlist.get(counterFilter),);
                        ii++;


                    }*/
                }
            }


            results.values = nlist;

            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }
```

The output is fine... but the child items are not according to the Parent item. I am not sure what to do.. I guess I have to find an alternative way to add child to the list than the following existing method..

```
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Afghanistan);//Header,Child data
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Albania);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Algeria);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), Andorra);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), Angola);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), Anguilla);
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Setting up the getChild() and getChildrenCount() properly solved it.

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.filteredDatachild.get(this.filteredData.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}



public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this.filteredDatachild.get(this.filteredData.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }
```

and creating the new child list like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);


                nchildlist.put(nlist.get(ii),originalDatachild.get(nlist.get(ii)));
                ii++;
                Log.d( "Child Items:", "Child index:" + ii);
            }
```

Comment: If order is important use LinkedHashMap